# Does the Macintosh classic have the signatures of the original Mac team?

Tags: mac, hardware, classic-mac-os, motherboard

I am huge fan of Apple, and I just bid on one a 1990-era Macintosh Classic. The bid is going higher, but I only want it if the computer has the signatures of the original Mac team.

It's before I was born, I wish I was born in that era. But please let me know if anyone knows whether this model has those signatures. I am 100% sure the original Macintosh (128k) had those signatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The signatures were really only in the 128K. Each time some the case saw some minor modification, some of the signatures would be cut off in part or in whole. The 512K Mac contained some of the signatures, and the Macintosh Plus contained a few less. At some point, the signatures disappeared entirely.

The Macintosh Classic was an entirely new case design, though, six years later. There were no signatures on it.

Also, not being fully satisfied, I found a picture:

- [Cracking Open the Apple Macintosh Classic](http://www.cnet.com.au/photos-inside-the-apple-macintosh-classic-339290389.htm#image2)

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a link to a picture I found online which shows the inside of the case. It's plain. :)